# How would you procedurally edit an object to have more faces while enforcing a circular shape?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Using Geometry Nodes I'd like to know how to make a shape more circular depending on the number of sides the shape has.

For example the below image shows 5 different cylinder meshes created with a different number of sides. If I started with the 4 sided shape, could Geometry Nodes subdivide it to add more vertices and then shift the vertex transform to the correct position to form a perfect circle?

Number of sides in the below image from left to right:
4, 8, 16, 32, 64

[image]

Comment: Just use the *Mesh Circle* geometry node. there you can specify the amount of vertices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cluster will cast the object-XY  profile of any geometry to a circle of radius `Radius` about the object origin.

[image]

[image]